# Howto connect to the local Google Cloud Taskqueue with Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've the following code which connects to Google Cloud Taskqueue and lease some Task:

```
    List<String> scopes=new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.addAll(DatastoreOptions.SCOPES);
    scopes.add(STORAGE_SCOPE);
    scopes.add(TaskqueueScopes.TASKQUEUE);

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(System.getenv("DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(System.getenv("DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE")))
        .build();

    taskqueue = new Taskqueue.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .setTaskqueueRequestInitializer(new TaskqueueRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initializeTaskqueueRequest(TaskqueueRequest<?> request) {
                    request.setPrettyPrint(true);
                }
            })
            .build();

    Taskqueue.Tasks.Lease leaseRequest =
            taskQueue.tasks().lease(APPLICATION_ID, TASK_QUEUE_NAME, 5, 30);
    Tasks tasks=leaseRequest.execute();

    /*... and I'm doing something with the leased tasks ....*/
```

The code uses service account configured in my project.
The code is standalone java application which will be running in the Google Compute Engine instance and will perform some background processing tasks.

Maybe you noticed Datastore and Storage scopes in the credentials. It's because my code communicates with the Storage and Datastore as well, but I put there only code snippet related to the Taskqueue for simplicity.

The code works perfectly, it connects to the Taskqueue running in the Google cloud. The Taskqueue is **pull** queue and is configured in my another application, the GAE web application which is creating tasks and storing them into the queue.

Now I'd like to debug my code locally so I need that my code connects to the **local** Taskqueue, running in the local debug server (localhost:8888) instead of the Taskqueue hosted in the google cloud.

**How to modify the code so it will connect to the local taskqueue and NOT to the cloud-hosted taskqueue?**

Comment: Is this help you?,https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_task_queue_tests

Comment: Hmm, no. It can be used to test if the taskqueue exists and works, but this needs rewritting of my code for that purpose, such is not what I want.

Comment: Would using `if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) { //do something } else { //do something else}` work for you? I used this to work around differences between production and local in the Images API